# Display specific profile type in Views

Tags: views

Hi I'm trying to setup a View with the following criteria.

Select style: 1) Yellow 2) Green 3) Blue

I created an exposed filter for that. Easy so far.

I have created a Color content type that contains each color style in a different View Mode. Let's say the user picks Yellow. Now i want all the Color nodes to be displayed with only the Yellow View Mode.

It's probably a simple solution but i can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a bit more about the installation you're using, Views version, Drupal version etc?

Comment: An Exposed Filter would do the job, add the style field as a filter and then expose it to the user with the relevant settings for your situation.

Comment: A simple trick is to make 3 views (or 3 displays) and restrict the display with Roles.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a filter on the relevant "style-field".
2. Change it's settings to be "Exposed"

And that's all you need. See [Taming the beast: Learn Views with NodeOne](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone/2011-03-21) for a good intro to the Views module.